# COGNOS 10-Workspace Advanced_Crosstab won't return Custom Query Calculation

Tags: sql, cognos-10

**COGNOS WORKSPACE ADVANCED 10**

I have a list of clients in a cross-tab report with metrics. Each client was queried using different date ranges and I want to display the minimum and maximum dates using two custom query calculations ( Minimum([Date YYYYMM]) and Maximum([Date YYYYMM].  When I drop these custom fields in the Y Axis, all of the metrics in the X axis return blank, and the Min/Max values in the Y Axis return as the field name, not the min/max value.

Example:

```
                                 X Axis: Channel Category & Metrics
```

Y Axis: Client | Min Date | Max Date

Comment: Can you show some specific examples of your data and the queries -- otherwise its *really* hard to determine what you are asking.

Comment: The query is fine.  Metrics populate when I don't add the min/max date fields.

Comment: Example:

                                 X Axis: Channel Category & Metrics  

Y Axis: Client | Min Date | Max Date

Comment: Is there a way to post a screenshot?

Comment: I figured it out.  I brought in the same Date YYYYMM field into the report, and edited the query expression for each.

Comment: MINIMUM([Date YYYYMM] FOR [Client ID])
MAXIMUM([Date YYYYMM] FOR [Client ID])
Not all items in my X Axis returned a value, causing multiple min/max values to return. To remedy this, I included the FOR operator to the expression on [client ID].
I can stop beating my head against the wall now :)